# Return multiple index Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

This is my query to the espn site for football data when I run the below code this returns only the first column not the full datatable

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://www.espn.in/soccer/table/_/league/eng.1","table",1)
```

When I run this `=IMPORTHTML("https://www.espn.in/soccer/table/_/league/eng.1","table",2)` it returns the datatable but it omits the first column which contains rowname.

Any suggestion how to include both of them?

Comment: yes i did acccept

Comment: Glad I could help. Thank you for taking the time to accept.

Comment: I saw the answer today ..so i was late in accepting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
=ArrayFormula(
     {REGEXREPLACE(IMPORTHTML("https://www.espn.in/soccer/table/_/league/eng.1","table",1),"^\d{1,2}\D{3}",""),
                   IMPORTHTML("https://www.espn.in/soccer/table/_/league/eng.1","table",2)})
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`REGEXREPLACE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)
- [`IMPORTHTML`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093339)

Comment: "^\d{1,2}\D{3}" what is this part can u explain me?